# Provide additional Status option for user_profile_form

Tags: users

I am writing the below code

```
     function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){
      if($form_id == 'user_register_form' && $form_id == 'user_profile_form'){
        $form['account']['status']['#options'] = array(0 =>'Blocked', 1=>'Active', 2 => 'Closed', 3 => 'Ractive');
        }
     }
```

I am able to see the options at user register form but not in user profile form. 
How to add other option on user profile edit.

Comment: have you written the correct user_profile form id. Check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, which only fires for a single form (`user_register_form` in this case).

If you want to use multiple forms in a single function, you need `hook_form_alter()`:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Anamika

Comment: I got one more issue with this. when I am fetching the value of status by $form_state['values']['status'] it shows only the key. If I do $form['status']['#options'][$form_state['values']['status']] still I am getting the key. How to check the value for the key?

Comment: Please describe what issue you are facing. You have written "If I do $form['status']['#options'][$form_state['values']['status']]", then ??

Comment: Can you post your issue as new question reference of this question. So it's for me or others to post answer. Because for question above my posting answer is sufficient. For your next issue you have to post as new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24254/discussion-between-nishantp-and-anamika).